# Remapping keyboard shortcuts to another key?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I am trying to remap keys on a web application so that if a user presses the 'Right' arrow key on their keyboard, it will to perform the same action as if they had pressed had pressed the 'CTRL-Shift-Right' keys?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your expected behaviour for "CTRL-Shit-Right" but I see 2 possible solutions:
1 - You bind an event (on keydown) to your window, check if its the right key, and do whatever ctrl+shitright was meant to do
2 - You trigger the event keydown/keyup/keypress with the values of CTRL-shift-right (create an instance of Event object and fill it)

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to use an event listener, something like

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',
            function (event) {
                 if (event.key === "something") {}
            });
```